# How to change fancytree SelectMode on a button click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, treeview, fancytree

I am using the a tree view/tree grid plugin which is called fancytree ([Here is the link](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki))

I initially (when the page loads) set the selectMode to 2 which allows the users to select multiple options.

```
        // Init 
    $("#Organizations .OrgTree").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var organizationUnitId = $this.data("orgid");
        //var treeData = JSON.parse($("#treeData_" + organizationUnitId).val());          
        $this.fancytree({
            extensions: ["persist"],
            selectMode: 2,
            persist: {
                expandLazy: true
                store: "auto" 'session': sessionStore
            },
            icons: false,
            checkbox: true,
            toggleEffect: null, //disable animations
            source: window["treeData_" + organizationUnitId], // treeData               
            lazyLoad: function (event, data) {
                var node = data.node;
                data.result = {
                    // Some data
                };
            }
        });
    });
```

What I want to do is, when I click on a button, I want to change the selectMode and set it to 1 or 3. 
I have tried to read through the documentation and found [this as well](https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/155)
But I won't work. Here is some code:

```
        //Bind click to search button
    $("#changeSelectModeBtn").click(function () {

        debugger;
        $("#Organizations .OrgTree").fancytree("getTree").visit(function (node) {
            node.setSelected(false);
        });

        $("#Organizations .OrgTree").fancytree({ selectMode: 3 });

        var selectedKeys = [];

        $("#Organizations .OrgTree").each(function () {

            var $this = $(this);
            var orgTree = $(this).fancytree("getTree");
            var selectedParentNodes = orgTree.getSelectedNodes();
            for (node in selectedParentNodes) {
                selectedKeys.push(selectedParentNodes[node].key)
            }

            // Save orgtree in hidden fields
            var organizationUnitId = $this.data("orgid");
            var treeData = orgTree.toDict(true);
            window["treeData_" + organizationUnitId] = treeData.children; //$("#treeData_" + organizationUnitId).val(JSON.stringify(treeData.children))

        });

        if (selectedKeys) {
            $("#HiddenOrganizationUnitIds").val(selectedKeys.join(","));
        }
    })
```

Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All options can be set dynamically using the jQuery widget pattern.
For example, you can use

```
$("#tree").fancytree("option", "selectMode", 3);
```

See also https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/wiki#configure-options

Comment: It was me who wrote that post. But Thanks a lot again :)